# How to export all rows groupped by filed?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have field `range` that contains diverse value:

```
1
300
1000
500
500
```

How can I get all rows groupped by `range`?

For example I need to get:

```
One row: 1

One row: 300

One row: 1000

Two rows: 500
```

How to export all rows to file `CSV` groupped by filed?

Comment: One remark, I dont know values in field `range`

Comment: can you please explain your output. do you want count as text along with the range?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to get the number of rows for each value of 'range', then you can do the following:

```
SELECT range, COUNT(*)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY range
```